# Tensorflow v2, corrupted record at 519390255 during training and cannot resume

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

im using Tensorflow v2 and Resnet50 as a model, and during trainingg an error occured at about 8000 steps.

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: {{function_node _*wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_16_device*/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} corrupted record at 519390255
[[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
[[RemoteCall]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

it seems to be a corrupted record file?

I haven't tried anything yet but could reuploading the tfrecord solve it and would it restart my training process to 0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've already figured it out but it's not exactly solving the problem as it continue to show the error sometimes, The problem is that during training an error occurs stating corrupt record file at 423213( note that i am using tensorflow v2 from https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html and using my own computer ryzen 5 3500X without the GPU )  The record file generated from the dataset for training is corrupted or a part of it is corrupted , to solve the issue i replaced the dirty record(corrupted record file) with a newly generated record file